# Extending Laptop display to two monitors

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I want to connect two monitors to extend (Not duplicate) my laptop's screen using one HDMI port (I also have a Mini Display Port, but would rather use the HDMI for both monitors because of port placement on the laptop). The Laptop is 7 years old and running Windows 10.

```
         - Monitor #1 (HDMI Input)
       /
HDMI -
       \
         - Monitor #2 (HDMI Input)
```

I was just going to buy an HDMI splitter, but online articles say that Windows will only recognize it as one screen, and the two monitors will show the same content.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Windows will only recognize it as one screen*... No, this is a huge misunderstanding. It has nothing to do with Windows or any other OS for that matter. This is how the hardware works. The computer is not aware there are 2 monitors connected, never. From its POV there's only one output (HDMI) in use and the OS is only aware of what the hardware recognizes.. The splitter does the rest by itself, it isn't and can't be controlled from within the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have answered your own question with your comment about the HDMI splitter! There may be a piece of hardware that will let your HDMI port be split over 2 monitors (so both monitors are half of one picture) but you would need to look that up. You might be able to get a USB video card or a dock, but that has its own issues.

If you need 2 extra screens, you have a Mini Display port as well. Just use that.

Comment: Wait, so an HDMI splitter supports extending my laptop screen across two monitors (So three screens total)? Everything I see suggests the opposite. I know I can use the Mini DP, but I would rather not (Its in a poor spot)

Comment: @Greenreader9 Perhaps you need to check the meaning of "may be". Randomhero isn't saying there is one, just that it isn't outside of the real of possibility. The point being what you want doesn't and can't exist as I explained in the comment under the question. Nothing can change one output into two different ones able to be managed with software, end of story.